# Как проверить является ли строка числом int/float

Tags: python, telebot

```
def check_flight_hours (message: types.Message):
    #если не число то повторный ввод
    if message.text.isdigit():
        night_hours = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите количество ночных часов:  " )
        bot.register_next_step_handler(night_hours, check_night_hours)

    # проверяем ввел ли число юзер
    else:
        flight_hours = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите количество летных часов:  ")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(flight_hours, check_flight_hours)
```

Comment: @oleksandrigo я должен данную функцию добавить в предыдущую или if is_number (message.text): автоматически ссылается на функцию def is_number для проверки? потому что все равно не пропускает число с точкой

Comment: Убрал из функции int(stroka) и стал принимать как обычные так и вещественные числа

Comment: Это я перестарался

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К примеру так

```
def is_number(stroka: str):
    try:
        float(stroka)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def check_flight_hours (message: types.Message):
    # если не число то повторный ввод
    if is_number(message.text):
        night_hours = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите количество ночных часов:  " )
        bot.register_next_step_handler(night_hours, check_night_hours)

    # проверяем ввел ли число юзер
    else:
        flight_hours = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите количество летных часов:  ")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(flight_hours, check_flight_hours)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
print("да" if re.fullmatch(pattern=r"\d+[.]\d+", string="3.14") else "нет")
```

Comment: Строки `-1`, `.2`, `1e5`, `inf` и `nan` являются float-числами, но вашу проверку не пройдут

Comment: Да, совершенно верно

Comment: Впринципе, можно усложнить регулярку и будет счастье, но с try except, наверное, будет проще